# Prevent access to image link

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm developing a upload file feature using ASP.NET Core

Every user upload their images to a seperate folder: `wwwroot/images/{userId}/{filename}.jpg`

The issue is if other users (eg: userId = 3) with their ID know other user's ID (eg: userId = 1) and his/her image file name uploaded, so they can easily access his/her file by using the URL by format above: `https://localhost:3333/images/1/user1Secret.jpg`

I want to restrict every user's images in their folder that only logged in user can access their own image, other user or not-login-user cannot access these image by using the URL format in the browser address bar, it may return a 403 page or somewhat

How can I do that?
Thanks all

Comment: I'm not sure you should be giving anyone access to folders on your server; potential large security issues. Better approach is to use the web interface to list files for that user to selectively download.

Comment: @PeterSmith just an example, images may be uploaded to the server that only contains image, or a cloud service that contains images such as azure....

Comment: I still think it is an unsafe approach; you need to be setting privileges on wherever you have the images. Properly managed web interface is the safe way top go.

Comment: could you tell me more detail about the safe way

Comment: I'm afraid that is too big a question, and answer, for here. In outline, authenticate the user, use the ID from authentication to point to the local folder and then list the files in that folder (names only) for the user with a selection mechanism. Then create a download for the selected file(s).

Comment: Don't use enumerable user id's. If I'm a user of your application I shouldn't be able to easily guess other users user id's, they should be randomized, not incrementing numbers. By itself this does not make a secure solution, but coupled with lacking authorization checks elsewhere, you make it way too easy for an attacker to grab data that does not belong to him/her.

Comment: @Rena, sorry friend. I haven't try your solution below. I'll try it later on free time, then response your answer asap. Thanks guy

Comment: Ok. Waiting for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the following document about Static file authorization first:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#static-file-authorization

Here is the whole working demo:

1.Move `images` folder outside of `wwwroot`.

2.Add such action in any of controllers:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("myimages/{userId}/{filename}")]
public IActionResult Image(string userId,string filename)
{
    var CurrentUserId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

    if (CurrentUserId == userId)
    {
        var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                                "images", userId, filename);
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower();
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
        //get the mimetype of the file
        string mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();

        return PhysicalFile(file, mimeType);
    }
    return new ForbidResult();
}
```

3.Configure Startup.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "images")),
    RequestPath = "/myimages"
});

app.UseAuthorization();
```